# Arquivo perdido no xCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ide, organização-de-projeto

Quando copio um arquivo Swift e colo ele da minha pasta, ele não aparece no xCode.

[image: xCode]

[image: Pasta com arquivos]

Comment: Nunca usei o xCode mas só colar não basta, tem que incluir no projeto.

Comment: encontrei aqui, click no folder do projeto > Add Files to "-"

Comment: desculpa a pergunta besta xD, é que algumas plataformas não precisa incluir como por exemplo o android studio, como não vi nenhum lugar pra dar include pensei que era algum bug...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De forma geral IDEs organizam os projetos internamente e para adicionar um arquivo ao projeto é preciso fazer perlo IDE, não pode só colar na pasta do projeto.

É questionável um IDE ficar monitorando a pasta para adicionar um arquivo colado ali automaticamente.

No caso do XCode é junto da criação do projeto, `Add Files To`:

[image: xCode Add Files To]